# activating virtualenv in windows which was created in ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

I created a `virtualenv` in ubuntu for one of my projects. Later I wanted to use the same `virtualenv` in windows and tried activating it using only the `activate` command

But the environment it activated had name `root` instead of the original one. 
Also I **could not import python libraries** which were installed in the same environment in Ubuntu.

**Things to note :** I wanted to use python3 for this project, so initialized it with python3 in ubuntu. Whereas in windows , I have only python2. Does this have to do anything with the issue

Answer (score 2):

You'll not be able to use a virtual environment created in Linux on Windows or vice versa. The installation files for different packages and libraries would be different for both the platforms, and you will not be able to use the raw Linux binaries on Windows anyway.

If you want to maintain parity in virtual environments, I suggest you write a script for the setting up process of virtual environment, and use it to create two different virtual environment, one for Windows and one for Linux.

Also, you'll need Python versions on both systems, unless your codebase is compatible with both Python2 and Python3.